# start a char array from a certain index

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have a char array called data.

I should write a method that makes it possible to return the array but with a starting point that is an integer variable called beginIndex.

Example: array contains 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' and beginIndex = 2. Then it should return 'B', 'C', 'D' (yes the index himself in this case the 2nd letter should be included as well!)

How do I do this? Or is it wiser to change it into a String and later change it back into a char array?

Comment: Any reason for not using Substring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a method for this. This is what it looks like:

```java
public static char[] charIndex(char[] chars, int beginIndex) {
    beginIndex--;
    char[] result = new char[chars.length - beginIndex];
    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if(!(i < beginIndex)) result[i - beginIndex] = chars[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here's how you use it:

```java
char[] chars = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars));
chars = charIndex(chars, 2);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars));
```

The output will be:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
[b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the method `Arrays.copyOfRange` ([Link to the Java 11 Documentation for this method](http://Link%20to%20the%20Java%2011%20Documentation%20for%20this%20method))

Parameters of this method are:

1. The original array
2. the index to start from, inclusive
3. the final index of the range, exclusive

An example how to use it:

```java
char[] originalArray =  {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
char[] secondArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(originalArray, 1, test.length);
```

In this example `secondArray` contains only 'b', 'c' and 'd'.

---

A method for your needs, where the the input equals the index-1 could look like this:

```java
public static char[] arrayFromPosition(char[] array, int position) {
  return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, position-1, array.length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below function, its based on 0-index

```
    public Character[] stripCharArrFromIndex(Character[] arr,int index){
        int arrSize = arr.length;
        Character[] strippedArr = new Character[arrSize - index];
        
        int j=0;
        for(int i=index;i<arrSize;i++){
            strippedArr[j]=arr[i];
            j++;
        }
        return strippedArr;
         
     }
```